# Load rake files and run tasks from other files

Tags: rake, rakefile

Currently I'm trying split up my rake files to organize them better. For this, I've added a `rake` folder to my `assets` dir, that holds one rake file for each group of tasks.

As I'm coming from PHP, I've only *very basic* knowledge of Ruby/Rake and can't get my namespaces default action running after loading the file.

The commmented out `Rake :: Task ...`-string inside `app:init` throws an error at the CL at me:

> ```
> rake aborted! 
> uninitialized constant TASK
> ```

Here's the namespace/class (if this is the right word).

```
task :default => [ 'app:init' ]
namespace :app do

    rake_dir   = "#{Dir.pwd}/assets/rake/"
    rake_files = FileList.new( "#{rake_dir}*" )

    desc "Loads rake modules (Default action)"
    task :init do
        puts "\t Importing rake files for processing"

        puts "\t loading..."
        rake_files.each() { |rake|
            puts "\t #{rake}"
            require rake
            # @link rubular.com
            name = rake.split( rake_dir ).last.gsub( /.rb\z/, '' )
            puts "\t #{name}"
            #Rake :: Task[ "#{name}:default" ].invoke
        }
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** At least, I can be sure the file gets loaded, as the plain `puts "file loaded"` at the beginning of those files gets echoed. The problem seems to *only* be that the `:default` action for the namespace in the loaded rake file isn't loading.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can either put your tasks into `rakelib/` folder which `rake` loads by default or add a specific folder in your `Rakefile` via:

```
Rake.add_rakelib 'lib/tasks'
```

Comment: Never knew about this. Thanks!

Comment: One improvement: You could mention that single files can easily be loaded using `load "file.rb"`. Then this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer should be protected. I never knew about this `rakelib/` directory

Answer (score 40):

If your goal is to load rake tasks from an external file, then you can do that as follows.  First, let's say you have a rake task in a file called `<project>/lib/tasks/hello.rake` that looks like this:

```
desc "Say hello"
task :hello do 
  puts "Hello World!"
end
```

Then you can create a simple `Rakefile` in your `<project>` directory to load it like this:

```
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}

desc "Say goodbye"
task :goodbye do
  puts "See you later!"
end
```

Of course, this will load all files ending with the `rake` extension.  You can simply load `hello.rake` like this:

```
load './lib/tasks/hello.rake'

desc "Say goodbye"
task :goodbye do
  puts "See you later!"
end
```

To see all the tasks that have been loaded use `rake -T`.  Note that I've used `lib/tasks` since that's the standard approach taken by Rails applications.  You could use `assets` or whatever you prefer, though I prefer `lib/tasks` even in non-Rails projects.  I also tend to separate my task files based on their namespace.

Comment: why does it have to be load and not require?

Comment: `require` is part of Ruby proper, but `load` is part of the Rake DSL.  It doens't have to be load, though.  Rake provides other, perhaps more explicit, ways to do this.  For example: `Dir.glob('tasks/**/*.rake').each { |r| Rake.application.add_import r }`

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `Rake.add_rakelib 'tasks'`, as @splattael said. One thing you need to know, the files in 'tasks' directory need have an extension of '.rake' instead of '.rb', otherwise, rake won't load it for you.

Sample file:

- https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/blob/master/Rakefile
- https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/tree/master/tasks

After you do all of the above, use `rake -T` to check your job to see whether rake has load your tasks successfully.